# Canvas rotation issue

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas

I'm trying to rotate view with google map v2

I used some small lib which work fine with google map v1

the problem is that rotation does not have an effect.

code snippet:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.rotate(-mHeading, getWidth() * 0.5f, getHeight() * 0.5f);
    mCanvas.delegate = canvas;
    super.dispatchDraw(mCanvas);

    canvas.restore();
}
```

mHeading - angel (not 0)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, because google maps v2 use SurfaceView for map rendering